Is it legal to emulate Nintendo Switch games if you dump your own games?
I'm about to receive my shiny new Steam Deck and plan to use the Mig Switch Dumper to dump and emulate (and mod) my library of Nintendo Switch games. However, a friend of mine thinks it's illegal to play Nintendo Switch games on anything other than Nintendo consoles intended to run said games. Who is right:

Me, who thinks that as long as you dump your personal copies of the games and don't distribute them, it is legal to emulate (and mod) them.
My friend, who thinks that emulating Nintendo Switch games is illegal no matter what.


Related meta

Technically, the DMCA does make that illegal, but depending on jurisdiction there are exceptions or deliberate non-enforcement for personal use. You probably need to ask at [law.SE].

@OrangeDog Is it OK for me to just copy/paste the question?

I may be wrong, we already closed questions asking if something is illegal as off-topic, iirc

not an answer, just advice: be careful to never launch two copies (one emulated, one real) of the same game at the same time. each cartridge has a unique id and nintendo can tell if the same id pops up on two machines simultaneously. (and, for the same reason: do not share your rom dumps.)

@WoodrowBarlow Yeah, I know. However, I think it doesn't matter unless I try to somehow play the emulated game online.
